# Is It Possible To Use The IBM WebSphere JAX-WS Runtime To Generate Web Services In Eclipse 4.x?

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere, jax-ws, websphere-7

I'm attempting to generate a JAX-WS server top down (from a WSDL) for the IBM WebSphere v7 runtime using Eclipse Kepler. The problem I'm running into is that I simply cannot select the web service runtime to be IBM WebSphere JAX-WS, there is no option for it. I've installed the WebSphere Application Server Developer Tools plugin for Kepler and configured the runtime in Eclipse to be the runtime installed on my system. I can also compile applications against the WAS 7 runtimes and deploy them to a WAS 7 server, so it would appear the runtimes are available.

The biggest thing that's frustrating me is that the option is available in Eclipse Indigo (3.x). To make sure there wasn't something awry with my work space or install in any way, I downloaded fresh copies of both versions of Eclipse, started with fresh work spaces, and installed the WAS 7 plugin on both versions from the marketplace. Eclipse 3.x gives me the option, but 4.x does not.

Now, I know these plugins are different versions. The version provided by the marketplace for Eclipse 4.x is 8.5.5011.v20131031_0202 while the version for 3.x is 8.5.1002.v20130402_2058, which based on the version number appears to be about 7 months older. This leads me to my question, is it possible to use the IBM WebSphere JAX-WS runtime to generate web services in Eclipse 4.x anymore? I've tried searching the web all I can but have found no mention of this ability being removed from the plugin. I've even found [other SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618679/java-eclipse-webservice-deployment-websphere-7-0) that make it seem like this once was available for Eclipse 4.x, but maybe no longer is with the latest version of the plugin (this linked question is over a year old). Does anyone know the answer to this. Is it no longer possible to do this, or is it actually possible by some other means that that you could share please?

Comment: Did you try the WebSphere forum? https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/forum?id=11111111-0000-0000-0000-000000000266

Comment: @dbreaux didn't think of it at first, but I did eventually post yesterday at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=29712397-fdfd-41be-8668-ada56447711a. I've had one response there, no resolution to my issue yet though. Sounds like it should still be available, maybe just something wrong with something I'm doing. I plan to update this appropriately once I have a resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is fixed now (see https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=29712397-fdfd-41be-8668-ada56447711a). The version of the plugin didn't change, but it sounds like there was an update to the plugin that fixed a bug.